# Simulate ctrl alt del in react-vnc

Tags: javascript, reactjs, vnc

Start to using [react-vnc](https://github.com/roerohan/react-vnc) to connect `wss` api (cloud server) on `reactjs` project

```
<VncScreen
      url='ws://your-vnc-url.com'
      scaleViewport
      background="#000000"
      style={{
        width: '75vw',
        height: '75vh',
      }}
      ref={ref}
    />
```

everything looks good and it connect successfully, but on windows screen of server I need press <kbd>ctrl+alt+del</kbd> to unlock, but I don't know how can I do this via react or react-vnc , is there any solution for this?

Is there any way to simulate `ctrl+alt+del` key on javascript or in `react-vnc` if not, so how can I press any key on `vnc` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The onConnect, onDisconnect, and onCredentialsRequired callbacks can accept a single parameter rfb. This parameter is the RFB object, which is described by noVNC. Learn more about the RFB object here.

The RFB object should provide a method called `sendCtrlAltDel` (see [API](https://github.com/novnc/noVNC/blob/master/docs/API.md#rfbsendctrlaltdel)). Maybe you can listen for a specific keypress and call this function instead.

**EDIT:**

You could receive the RFB object on the 'connect' event and use it later. Then you could create a button on your UI and invoke the `rfb.sendCtrlAltDel()` function when the button is clicked.

I'm not very familiar with React, but with the following example you might get the idea.

```js
import { VncScreen } from 'react-vnc';

class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.rfb;
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <VncScreen
        url='ws://your-vnc-url.com'
        onConnect=(rfb) => this.rfb = rfb
        // ...
      />

      <button onclick="this.rfb.sendCtrlAltDel()">
        CTRL + ALT + DEL
      </button>
    );
  }
}
```

**Edit:** Solution for functional component:

```
import {VncScreen} from "react-vnc";
const ref = useRef();

    <VncScreen
        url={res.data.wssUrl}
        scaleViewport
        background="#000000"
        rfbOptions={
            {
                credentials: {
                    password: res.data.password
                }
            }
        }
        onConnect={(rfb) => ref}
        style={{
            width: '100%',
            height: '100vh',
        }}
        ref={ref}
        loadingUI={true}
    />

    <Button onClick={()=>ref.rfb.sendCtrlAltDel()}>ctrl+alt+del</Button>
```

Comment: Okay, it seems my solution, but still I don't know how to call `sendCtrlAltDel` in `react-vnc` I read doc, but still confused

Comment: Excellent Arber!, based on your answer I figured out the solution, I edited your answer with correct approach for peoples in futures